# Always automatically choose "Close the program"

Tags: windows-7

Windows is constantly offering me prompts like this one when my programs crash:

[image: crash prompt]

I choose "Close the program" about 100% of the time. Is there a way to disable these prompts and just automatically go the route of "Close the program"? Thanks.

Comment: Windows makes for an excellent Emacs bootloader.

Comment: Sorry but Emacs is nothing but rubbish on Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [WER Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638(VS.85).aspx#DontShowUI) MSDN article:

> Use Regedit, navigate to the below path:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\DontShowUI]
```

> Create a DWORD and set the value to 1.

Comment: Thanks, though I had to set the value to `1`, not `0`.

Comment: @Jackson Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Control Panel / Action Center / Change Action Center settings / Problem reporting settings / Change report settings for all users/ "Never check for solutions (not recommended)"

Comment: This removes the "Check online for a solution" option, but the prompt still appears. I'd like for the prompt to not appear at all and for the program to be closed automatically.